# python exec problem: why cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: python, exec

I tested these under python 2.6 and 2.7.
`See this is OK:`
>>> exec 'e=1'
>>> exec 'f=2'
>>> exec 'g=e+f'
>>> print g
**3**

`But this returns error:`
>>> cont=['e=1','f=2','g=e+f']
>>> for e in cont:
...     try:
...             exec e
...     except Exception,em:
...             print em
...
**cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects**

So why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've chosen your variable names poorly. You're using `e` as both the `for` loop variable and the int variable in `cont[0]`. What happens is that the first time through the loop, `e == 'e=1'`; then `exec e` is called and `e == 1`; then the next time through the loop, `e == 'f=2'`, and so on. By the time the last expression `'g=e+f'` is `exec`ed, `e` is no longer an int, but a string -- the string `'g=e+f'`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `e` as the variable for your loop. Naturally, it contains a string since that's what the list contains. Use another name instead.